# Strange self-answers

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

In [Rails 2.1.0 Gem Missing - RVM, Passenger, Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349476/rails-2-1-0-gem-missing-rvm-passenger-apache), the asker posted his progress as answers without any direct solutions. I'm not sure how I should flag these, but I think they are not truly answers. I considered "For Moderators" (because there are multiple answers) or "not verifiable anymore" (because he has no idea what fixed it in particular) or "not an answer."

Or are these answers considered okay?

Comment: A downvote for now is fine if you feel like the answer is poor.  Only one of those answers needs to exist, but it is indeed cryptic.  When I have time later I'll peruse this to see if the *question* needs to be scrutinized closer.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time someone asked a easy question to double dip with a pre-prepared self answer. That was why accepted self answers no longer sticky to the top.

Comment: The user posted things that worked for them, one of them just happens to have downsides while the other ultimately solved their problem to the point of acceptance. I don't see an egregious problem here.

Comment: @BoltClock - Maybe you are right, I'm actually not very deep into Rails but both of his answers seemed very alike. But is there is actually a substantial difference? When I want to add another answer SO tells me "Are you sure you want to add another answer? You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead" which I see as "Edit old one if they are very alike". But I'm still new, that's why I asked.

Comment: Seems to me that they should have been combined into a single answer. We did have edit functionality back in 2010. A "tried this, didn't work" answer is unlikely to be helpful to anyone.

Comment: @CodyGray If an answer tells you, that "formatting your computer" won't solve your problem, I suppose it has had some value?

Comment: @CodyGray that may be part of the question, right? "I did this, didn't get the desirable result"